# Facing tiles issue while migrating struts 1.3 to struts 2.5.29

Tags: jboss, mbeans, jboss-4.0.x

I am facing issue while migrating struts 1.3 to struts 2.5.29.
struts 2.5.29 code is deployed in jboss-4.0.5.GA .
I have referred from example
https://www.viralpatel.net/struts-2-tiles-plugin-tutorial-with-example-in-eclipse/

Getting below exception and no other error:

```
[main] WARN org.jboss.system.ServiceController - Problem starting service jboss.web.deployment:war=abc.war,id=-974944616
    deployment failed
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:375)
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:103)
            at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:371)
            at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
            at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    
    
    
    --- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
    ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=abc.war,id=-974944616
      State: FAILED
      Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:...../abc.war/ deployment failed
    
    --- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
    ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=abc.war,id=-974944616
      State: FAILED
      Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:........... deployment failed

Can anyone help on this?
```

Comment: Version conflict canbe resolved upgrading to the new version.

Comment: tried with Struts 6.0.3 version as well and same issue persists..

Comment: You have nothing to do with Struts, because it's not its problem.

Comment: ok. If its not a struts version issue then you mean it is tiles version issue? We are using tiles 3.0 in our project.

Comment: It's not a tiles version issue. You should read the message of the error.